# 2005 Chrysler 300

Tags: power-loss, chrysler-300

So I have a 2005 Chrysler 300 I was driving down the freeway it was not overheating but it lost power and a lot of smoke came out of the hood I opened it oil spill all over no oil no water in the spark plugsthe water was not there what could it be

Comment: Was the oil cap left off the engine?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How many miles on this vehicle? How many miles do you think this car will go before it totally dies?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities here but the fix is to determine where the oil is coming from and correct that problem.

First of all, check the simple things like the oil fill cap and the oil filter.  These can be loose and leaking and when the oil hits hot components, like exhaust, you get the smoke.

There may also be an oil leak coming from somewhere else like the transmission oil cooler lines that go from the transmission, up beside the engine and to connections on the radiator.  Leaks in these lines can spray transmission oil all over the place that cause smoking.

Another possibility is the power steering pump and lines which also contain oil under pressure that can spray out and smoke.

Wait until the engine cools off and the smoke dissipates and then look with a flashlight and see if you can tell where the oil is coming from.  If you have to, start the engine and carefully look for oil leaking.

Comment: So my boyfriend did all that he couldent detect where the oil leak came from but he cleaned it up and we bought the blue devil as we poured in to the radiator hose we topped it with water and as water gos in the water came out from the thermostat bolts were loose so now my question is should i be concerned bout leaving the blue devil in the radiator till we try to fix the thermostat problem

Comment: I just want my car to work again im so scared that the heads maybe got blown

Comment: It has 209356 miles